# XPath query to modify an xml document in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to change the 'test-data1' string via Xpath and C#. Couldnt get any close to even get the value in the first place.

Any help appreciated.

```
<Dashboard>
  <Title Text="view1" />
  <DataSources>
    <SqlDataSource Name="DS1" ComponentName="sqlDataSource1">
      <Connection Name="DEV1" ConnectionString="test-data1" />
      <Connection Name="DEV2" ConnectionString="test-data2" />
      <ConnectionOptions CloseConnection="true" />
    </SqlDataSource>
  </DataSources>
</Dashboard>
```

I've tried `xml.XPathSelectElement("//SqlDataSource/Connection/@ConnectionString");` 
to read the data as well, but it gets null. I want to change the test-data1 or test-data2 via code.

Comment: `xml.SelectSingleNode("//SqlDataSource/Connection[@ConnectionString='test-data1']')`  This will get you the `Connection` node so you can change its attributes.

Comment: I query is to read data, not write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XPathSelectElement` will only be able to select elements from your document, whereas your XPath is attempting to select an attribute.

So instead, you can select the parent element specifically like this, and use `SetAttributeValue` to change the attribute.

```
var connectionElement = xml.XPathSelectElement("//SqlDataSource/Connection[@Name='DEV1']");
connectionElement.SetAttributeValue("ConnectionString", "Hello, world");
```

If you do not know the name of the connection, instead you can iterate the collection of Connection elements to perform your action by using `XPathSelectElements` instead, which will return potentially many elements matching the XPath. For example, if you wanted to just change the first Connection element encountered, you could do:

```
var connectionElement = xml.XPathSelectElements("//SqlDataSource/Connection").First();
connectionElement.SetAttributeValue("ConnectionString", "Hello, world");
```

Using `First()` in this case to take the first connection element - equally you could use `ElementAt` with an index, or any other Linq operation to target the desired connection.

Comment: Thanks @steve. But I won't know the name beforehand as well, so how can I select the attribute value without the name 'DEV1', but maybe by index or by someother means ?

Comment: Thanks @steve16351, I got it finally working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is there a way to get the original attribute value as well, before the setAttribute ? like connectionElement.GetAttributeValue("ConnectionString") ?

Comment: `connectionElement.Attribute("ConnectionString").Value`

Answer (score 0):

`XPathSelectElement` expects the query to select an element (`XElement`). You xpath query select an attribute, so it doesn't work well. Here's an example to modify the value of the connection string `DEV1`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = @"<Dashboard>...</Dashboard>";

        var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var item = document.XPathSelectElement("//SqlDataSource/Connection[@Name='DEV1']");
        item.SetAttributeValue("ConnectionString", "new value");
        Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());
        //document.Save("");
    }
```